# as.factor changes values of binary variable - this messes up my ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with logistic regression on an imported STATA dataset.

One of the variabels is a binary variabel, but is imported as atomic. I change this variable from atomic to factor after importing. When performing this  change R automatically changes the values from 0 and 1 to 1 and 2.

Who cares - it works fine? 
Yes, it does until I need to plot smoothed lines using ggplot.
Here I need to use as.numeric() in order to get the smoothed line in my plot. Because I use as.numeric the values plotted are now betweeen 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1. 
If I dont use as.numeric() the smoothed line does not appear.

Can you help me solve this?

Below code recreates the problem:

```
ID <- rep(1:10)
BIN <- rep(0:1, 10)
INDEPENDENT <- runif(10, min=1, max=100)
df <- as.data.frame.matrix(cbind(ID, BIN, INDEPENDENT))

# Please stop and inspect the values under BIN before running next line

df$BIN <- as.factor(df$BIN)

# Please reinspect the BIN values after running the as.factor line

df$BIN <- factor(df$BIN, levels = c(0,1), label = c("No", "Yes")) 

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(INDEPENDENT, as.numeric(BIN)))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "loess")+
  ylab("Now I have to write this annoying line explaining that: \n 1=No 
  2=Yes")
```

Comment: `as.numeric(BIN) - 1`? I don't get why you coerce to factor if you clearly want to treat it as numeric.

Comment: Hi Roland. Maybe its because of my inexperience in stats, but if I dont change it would it not give me problems when running the logistic models using the glm() function?

Comment: or you could just create an additional numeric variable (before you convert it to factor) that you use for plotting.

Comment: Thats also a nice  and simple solution. Thank you.

Comment: And there is no need for `df$BIN <- as.factor(df$BIN)` as you do `factor()`.

Comment: Or use `as.numeric(as.character(df$BIN))` - this converts the factor to its labels (0 and 1) and then to numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this solves your plotting problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
ID <- rep(1:10)
BIN <- rep(0:1, 10)
INDEPENDENT <- runif(10, min=1, max=100)
df <- as.data.frame.matrix(cbind(ID, BIN, INDEPENDENT))
df$BIN <- factor(df$BIN, levels = c(0,1), label = c("No", "Yes")) 

ggplot(df, aes(INDEPENDENT, BIN))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(aes(y = as.numeric(BIN)), method = "loess")
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful solution. Thank you very much!